# Python TicTacToe Error: TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python and I am trying to build a simple tic tac toe game.
However I am stuck on these two functions:

-With the first one (choose_position()) I want to check if the user input a number from 0 to 8 (the board is composed of a list)

-With the second one (check_if_can_x_o()) I want to assign the value 'X' if the position/spot in the board is not already filled.

```
def choose_position():
    position = int(input("Choose the position of your sign:\n"))
    if position in range(0, 9):
        return position
    else:
        print("That is not in the board")

def check_if_can_x_o():
    position = choose_position()
    if board[position] == "X" or board[position] == "O":
        print("\nYou can't go there. Try again")
    else:
        board[position] = "X"
```

I defined the board as following:

```
board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def board():
        print("""
            {} | {} | {}
            ---------
            {} | {} | {}
            ---------
            {} | {} | {}
    """.format(board[0], board[1], board[2], board[3], board[4], board[5], board[6], board[7], board[8]))
```

The error I get is the following: "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable".

Many thanks!

Comment: How is `board` defined?

Comment: If you're going to use the return value of `choose_position()`, you'd better make sure you return something useful from all code paths.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. The key to the bug lies in code that you haven't shown. It seems that you have defined `board` as a function (somewhere else) but in this non-self-contained code fragment you are trying to treat it as a list.

Comment: You can't have `board` be both a function and a list. Your second definition overwrites the first. Perhaps you could leave your original definition of `board` as a list alone and write a function called `print_board`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the issue is that you have an array board as well as function board therefore you need to rename one of them probably easiest to rename function to a new name e.g.
replace

```
def board():
```

with

```
def show_boards();
```